# Centering Windows on screen

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, nswindow, centering

Short and sweet: How can I tell Interface Builder to center a window on a user's screen?  I've seen the positioning tool on the inspector, but eyeballing doesn't always land as squarely as I like.  Is this something where I should switch over to Xcode and add something to the `init` or `awakeFromNib` methods?

Comment: Get the screen size, divide it by two, divide your window size by two and subtract the half of the screen size with the half of your window size. With size I mean: do it for X and do it for Y separately.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use `[window center]` as answered by wahkiz, but that might not be exactly what you want. The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000013-BCIBCBFC) states that this will put the window centered horizontally, but somewhat above the vertical centre. In this way the window has a visual prominence.

If you want to put your window in the *exact* centre, then manual positioning (as commented by Koning Baard XIV) will work for you.

Answer (score 7):

Use `[window center];` for the centre of the window to be centred to the screen.
Also, assuming you're in 10.5+, there is a centre to screen button in *Interface Builder*.

Comment: Where is the center to screen button?

Comment: My answer was written in 2011–that is 9 years ago. Unfortunately, I do not know if there is such a button anymore!

Answer (score 3):

In your appdelegate, in applicationfinishedlaunching, add this code at the bottom.

```
[window center];
```

Comment: Where does `window` come from?

Answer (score 0):

For macOS Mojave this worked for me, in `AppDelegate` `applicationDidFinishLaunching` for the Main Window:

```
[[[NSApplication sharedApplication] mainWindow] center];
```