# Center window in screen

Tags: macos, swift2, nswindowcontroller, nsviewcontroller

Is there any way to center a window in the center of the screen in OSX?

I am using the code below but it changes just the size but not the position on screen.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let ScreenStart = NSSize(width: (NSScreen.mainScreen()?.frame.width)! / 1.5, height: (NSScreen.mainScreen()?.frame.height)! / 1.5)

        self.view.frame.size = ScreenStart
        self.view.frame.origin = NSPoint(x: (NSScreen.mainScreen()?.frame.origin.x)!/2, y: (NSScreen.mainScreen()?.frame.height)! / 2)  
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Centering Windows on screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855034/centering-windows-on-screen)

Comment: Thanks but did not even found this

Answer (score 16):

For future references this is done inside `NSWindowController` class using `self.window?.center()`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question, when using a `Modal` presentation of a `NSTabViewController`.

I like this answer: [How to constrain second NSViewController minimum size in OS X app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52921266/how-to-constrain-second-nsviewcontroller-minimum-size-in-os-x-app)

I used `NSWindowDelegate` to access the `NSWindow` properties and functions.  This included `self.view.window?.center()` as @SNos said.

```
class YDtabvc: NSTabViewController, NSWindowDelegate {

    public let size = NSSize(width: 500, height: 800)

    override func viewWillAppear() {
        super.viewWillAppear()
        self.view.window?.delegate = self
        self.view.window?.minSize = size
        self.view.window?.center()

    }
    override func viewDidAppear() {
        super.viewDidAppear()
        var frame = self.view.window!.frame
        frame.size = size
        self.view.window?.setFrame(frame, display: true)
    }
}
```